# Smoothies: ice or cream?

Tags: smoothie

Smoothies are traditionally known to be a thick and sweet beverage. My question is, were they initially made with

(a) fruits and cream
(b) fruits and yogurt
(c) fruits, ice, and milk?

What I mean is, which of the recipes above are more "traditional" or more original, as with the first people who did it with blenders. Was it first done in the US?

Comment: Just a question, is a Indian Lassi be considered a smoothie ?

Comment: Is this only fruit-based smoothies (e.g., not a milkshake)?

Comment: I hope we can stick to fruit-based smoothies. But if you can connect it to milkshakes (ones that use ice cream?), the by all means.

Comment: Do you consider dairy an essential ingredient?

Comment: Your question is based on some assumptions which I find quite improbable. For example, that the earliest smoothies contained dairy. Or that smoothies made with one specific dairy became widespread before those made with other dairies. Or even that we can say which drinks should fall under the "smoothie" category and which shouldn't.

Comment: @Max if so, the history goes back [a few thousand years](https://www.desiblitz.com/content/history-of-lassi-the-yoghurt-drink)!

Comment: @rumtscho should this question perhaps be migrated to https://english.stackexchange.com/ as it is more about the etymology of the word 'smoothie' than any particular advice on how to make smoothies 'smoothier' ;)

Comment: @CosCallis I don't think it is about etymology. Nothing in this question seems interesting to a linguist for me. Maybe for a psycholinguist, but then it would be an applied example for which they would get their data from other disciplines such as anthropology and history of food. And we happen to allow history of food questions here. So I see it as on topic, but potentially unanswerable. Maybe even closable as "too broad", but not so obviously that it deserves a mod hammer, so the community will have to decide if it votes to close.

Comment: I have my context for asking the question, but in general it's really a historical query. Who first thought of using a blender to make a cold, thick beverage? And did they use yogurt, cream, or ice (like a Frappucino) to achieve it? Does anyone know or have insight?